# java 14 nullpointerexception no detailed message

Tags: java, java-14, openj9

Java 14 has many new features. One of them is showing detailed message in NullPointerException. I installed Java 14 and trying to compile and run below class but I am not getting any detailed message. Am I missing anything? please help.

```
~/code/demo/temp$ java -version
openjdk version "14" 2020-03-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK (build 14+36)
Eclipse OpenJ9 VM AdoptOpenJDK (build openj9-0.19.0, JRE 14 Mac OS X amd64-64-Bit Compressed          References 20200313_47 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
OpenJ9   - 0133ba037
OMR      - 1c04e0ef9
JCL      - a73be60649 based on jdk-14+36)

~/code/demo/temp$ cat Hello.java
public class Hello {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    String a = null;
    System.out.println(a.length());
  }
}

~/code/demo/temp$ javac Hello.java
~/code/demo/temp$ java -XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages Hello
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Hello.main(Hello.java:4)
```

I am passing suggested -XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages flag to java but there is no detailed message. Please help.

Comment: Have you made sure that your `javac` is version 14?

Comment: You are using OpenJ9. Found [this bug](https://github.com/eclipse/openj9/issues/8450)

Comment: [Release Notes of OpenJ9, stating it is not implemented](https://github.com/pmhayward/openj9-docs/blob/master/docs/version0.19.md#extended-messages-for-nullpointerexception-not-yet-implemented)

Answer (score 10):

OpenJ9 currently [does not support JEP 358](https://www.eclipse.org/openj9/docs/version0.19/#extended-messages-for-nullpointerexception-not-yet-implemented):

> ### Extended messages for `NullPointerException` not yet implemented
>
> [JEP 358: Helpful NullPointerExceptions](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/358) provides extended messages when a `NullPointerException` is generated by the Java 14 VM and you have enabled the feature. However, be aware that this is not implemented in OpenJ9 at this time.

The progress is tracked in [this bug](https://github.com/eclipse/openj9/issues/8450)

If you want to use this feature, download the hotspot variant from adoptopenjdk. It's the same vendor as your current distribution, so this is only a small change.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this. They should have mentioned this point in OpenJDK release notes. https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk/14/

Comment: @Pradeep OpenJ9 is developed by Eclipse, not Oracle.

Comment: @Pradeep OpenJ9 is not the same project as OpenJDK.

Answer (score -1):

I am keeping this here for clarification, since the OP didn't say what the expected output is.

The following example works because it is using the hotspot jvm.

```
public class Exceptional{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String a = null;
        try{
            System.out.println(a.length());
        } catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

This is pretty much the same program, except it is just showing the message.

```
~/local/jdk-14+36/bin/java Exceptional.java
```

> null

When run with the additional argument.

```
 ~/local/jdk-14+36/bin/java -XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages Exceptional.java
```

> Cannot invoke "String.length()" because "" is null

The argument also affects the stacktrace on the hotspot jvm.

When run without the additional argument:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at Exceptional.main(Exceptional.java:6)

And run with the argument:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.length()" because "" is null
>       at Exceptional.main(Exceptional.java:6)

I incorrectly thought the stack trace might not change because it already includes additional information about the code. As the other answer points out, it is a bug that is being addressed in the openj9 jvm.

Comment: It does not answer WHY op does not get any helpful nullpointerexception. Just a "Hey, you can get the message in your code with `e.getMessage()`".

Comment: @JohannesKuhn doesn't it though? They're letting the exception bubble up to a stack trace where as the argument is modifying the exceptions message. So I am showing that the message is getting changed.

Comment: The problem lies somewhere else. Even if op would run your code, it does not change the outcome (always `null` as message)

Comment: The message from `e.getMessage()` should be the same one shown in the stack trace if you don't catch the exception - unless you've tested this and observed a difference in the message between catching it vs. not catching it, then I don't think catching it addresses the issue in the question.

Comment: @kaya3 true, I updated it to include the behavior of the stack trace version too.

Comment: The OP stated that they add the command line option but it still doesn't work. So your answer is not applicable to their problem.

Comment: @RealSkeptic It doesn't solve their issue, but I think it is relevant because it shows the expected output of using their argument in an environment where it works.

Comment: @matt The down vote is presumably because you didn't answer the question. Even you acknowledge *"it doesn't solve their issue"*!