# How to enable helpful NullPointerExceptions in gradle test

Tags: java, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl, java-14

**This problem has been fixed in Gradle 6.6**

## Original post

I want to put the flag `-XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages` to enable helpful NPEs (https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/358) on the tests

I tried

```
tasks.withType<Test> {
    jvmArgs("-XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages")
    testLogging {
        setExceptionFormat("full") // Prints the message of the exception
    }
}
```

But the NPEs have still no messages.

Here's my java version

```
java -version
openjdk version "14.0.1" 2020-04-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 14.0.1+7)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 14.0.1+7, mixed mode, sharing)
```

**EDIT WITH MORE RESEARCH**

To find out more precisely the origin of the problem, I did some more work. My conclusion is that it doesn't come from my java nor the test framework, it can only be a misconfig of gradle or a bug.
Here's what i've done :

I've setup an empty gradle project with this build.gradle.kts

```
plugins {
    java
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13")
}
tasks.withType<Test> {
    jvmArgs("-XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages") // Helpful NPEs not working :(
    testLogging {
        setExceptionFormat("full") // Prints exception messages
    }
}
```

And with a test class (src/test/java/TestNPE.java)

```
import org.junit.*;

public class TestNPE {

    @Test
    public void true_npe() {
        Object o = null;
        o.toString();
    }

    @Test
    public void throw_npe() {
        throw new NullPointerException("My own message");
    }
}
```

So now

```
./gradlew test

> Task :test FAILED

TestNPE > throw_npe FAILED
    java.lang.NullPointerException: My own message
        at TestNPE.throw_npe(TestNPE.java:13)

TestNPE > true_npe FAILED
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at TestNPE.true_npe(TestNPE.java:8)

2 tests completed, 2 failed
```

This means the framework doesn't do anything special with NPEs.

After that, I retrieved the classpath gradle uses by running test with debug logs. With that, I could run JUnit directly. With -XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages the helpful NPE message shows up :

```
java -cp '/Users/apflieger/src/gradle-helpfull-npe/build/classes/java/test:/Users/apflieger/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/junit/junit/4.13/e49ccba652b735c93bd6e6f59760d8254cf597dd/junit-4.13.jar:/Users/apflieger/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3/42a25dc3219429f0e5d060061f71acb49bf010a0/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar' -XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages org.junit.runner.JUnitCore TestNPE
JUnit version 4.13
.E.E
Time: 0.006
There were 2 failures:
1) throw_npe(TestNPE)
java.lang.NullPointerException: My own message
    at TestNPE.throw_npe(TestNPE.java:13)
2) true_npe(TestNPE)
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "Object.toString()" because "o" is null
    at TestNPE.true_npe(TestNPE.java:8)

FAILURES!!!
Tests run: 2,  Failures: 2
```

Comment: Is this kotlin or groovy build file?

Comment: Kotlin it is, as this in my build.gradle.kts

Comment: You need to verify that your jvm supports that option. If you include this detail in your question, it would be easier to know how to help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java 14 nullpointerexception no detailed message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61042145/java-14-nullpointerexception-no-detailed-message)

Comment: I edited the question, adding java -version and the fact that I checked the option is working on my java

Comment: Can you show what error message you get when you run your test?

Comment: I believe the reason this doesn't work is probably because your testing framework is handling the nullpointer exception message before the JVM gets a chance to handle it. That's probably why when you run your regular application, you get the jvm's message because nothing is handling the exception

Comment: I did more research and edited the question under **EDIT WITH MORE RESEARCH**. I could exclude the jvm and the test framework

Comment: Maybe the problem is not specifically with Gradle, but with the gradle Test task. I will look into this

Comment: It's something with the test task, same code does show the NPE message with tomcat in my case

Answer (score 2):

This is a gradle problem, it will be working from gradle 6.6.

You can try:

```
@Test
public void true_npe() {
    try {
        Object o = null;
        o.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    }
}
```

The detailed message is in the printed stack trace but it's not in the junit error message

The problem is from gradle, I believe it's using Object Input/Output Stream to pass execution results from test vm to gradle vm. During this exchange the extended message from the original NPE is lost (is a native method).

You can workaround this with a custom junit 5 extension (should be similar for junit 4):

```
public class HelpfulNullPointerExceptionExtension implements TestExecutionExceptionHandler {
    @Override
    public void handleTestExecutionException(ExtensionContext context, Throwable throwable) throws Throwable {
        if (throwable instanceof NullPointerException) {
            NullPointerException extended = new NullPointerException(throwable.getMessage());
            extended.setStackTrace(throwable.getStackTrace());
            throw extended;
        }
        throw throwable;
    }
}
```

And register automatically in a META-INF/services/org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.Extension file with content

```
org.mypackage.HelpfulNullPointerExceptionExtension
```

Or, if you care about nested NPE:

```
public class HelpfulNullPointerExceptionExtension implements TestExecutionExceptionHandler {
@Override
public void handleTestExecutionException(ExtensionContext context, Throwable throwable) throws Throwable {
    Throwable actual = throwable;
    do {
        if (actual instanceof NullPointerException) {
            var field = Throwable.class.getDeclaredField("detailMessage");
            field.setAccessible(true);
            field.set(actual, actual.getMessage());
        }
        actual = actual.getCause();
    } while (actual != null && actual != throwable);
    throw throwable;
}
```

}

Comment: Awesome as a workaround, thanks. It still sounds like a bug, I opened an issue https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/13096

Comment: It will be working in upcoming gradle 6.6, see https://github.com/gradle/gradle/pull/13193

Comment: @apflieger can you accept that answer if it answerd/solved your problem?

Comment: Well, the problem has been fixed in Gradle